# how to rebuild widget when press the back button on device

Tags: flutter

So is it possible when  press  the back button on the phone it will rebuild the widget that am going to
like if  move from widget 1 to widget 2 and then pressed the back button to back to widget 1
Is there a way o rebuild it when  back to widget 1 .

Answer (score 1):

When you call the page you do:

```
await goToNextPage();// your navigation way
//rebuild you widget here
rebuildWidget();
```

the code will wait the page close to continue the code execution, then you can call safety the next lines will only run when the next page is closed.

Comment: well how could i do it using the device back button ?

Comment: It works when you use the back button too. The screen is waiting the second screen closes.